# Error FormGroup Angular

Tags: angular, formularios, angular-directivas, guards

```
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

<form [formGroup] ="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm.value)">
```

Tengo este error que hace referencia al `[formGroup]="loginForm"` en la vista del `login.component.html`, me esta generando ese problema ya busque por otros medios y dice que importe el FormModels y el FormReactiveModels lo tengo importado en el `app.module.ts` , `pages.modules.ts` y `auth.module.ts` aun asi me sigue saliendo este mismo error en el codigo no logro entender el porque, como tal me subraya el error el en el  `[FormGroup]` 
de  `login.component.html` 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son mis archivos de angular , espero que pueda asesorarme para solucionar el problema

```
login.component.html

<div class="hold-transition login-page">
  <div class="login-box" animate__animated animate__fadeOut>
    <div class="login-logo">
      <a href="login.component.html"><b>LOGIN VESPOT</b></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Inicio Formulario Login -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body login-card-body">
        <p class="login-box-msg">Bienvenido a Vespot SAS</p>
        <a href="./login.component.html" class="brand-link">
          <img src="./assets/dist/img/LogodeVespot.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="img-circle elevation-4 "
            style="opacity: .8" style="width:30%;margin-left:35%">
        </a>
        <form [FormGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm.value)">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="Correo">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <span class="fas fa-envelope" style="color: rgb(48, 37, 37);"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Contraseña">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <span class="fas fa-lock" style="color: rgb(48, 37, 37);"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="icheck-primary">
                <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
                <label for="remember" class="ml-2">
                  Recordar inicio de sesion
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Iniciar sesion-->
            <div class="col-4" style="margin-left: 74%;">
              <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-light">Entrar</button>
            </div>
            <!-- Iniciar sesion -->
          </div>
        </form>

        <div class="social-auth-links text-center mb-3 " id="my-signin2">

        </div>
        <!-- Adicionales -->

        <p class="mb-1">
          <a href="forgot-password.html" class="badge badge-light">Recordar contraseña</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- Adicionales -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Fin Formulario login -->
</div>
```

```
login.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(private readonly router: Router) { }

    loginForm = new FormGroup({
        email: new FormControl(),
        password: new FormControl()
    })


    private user: any = {
        email: 'test@gmail.com',
        password: '123456'
    }

    public login(data: any) {


        if (data.email == this.user.email && data.password == this.user.password) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', 'true');  
          return this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        }     
          return alert('Email o contraseña invalidos')
        
/* Hacer un servicio que lea el api como las credenciales que se estan pasando en este formulario
Cuando se reciban , hay que almacenarlos en un sitio */
    }

}
```

```
auth.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  exports:[LoginComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule

  ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

```
pages.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  exports:[LoginComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule

  ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

```
app.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PagesModule } from './pages/pages.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { ToastrModule } from "ngx-toastr";
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    PagesModule,
    AuthModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      timeOut: 3000,
      extendedTimeOut: 3000,
      positionClass: "toast-top-right",
      progressBar: true,
      closeButton: true,
      progressAnimation: "increasing",
      preventDuplicates: true,
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
auth.routing.module.ts


import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';


const routes: Routes = [

  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}

]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

```
admin.guards.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private readonly router: Router) { }

    canActivate(): boolean {


        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

        if (token) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
            return false;
        }

    }
}

/* cREAR UN SERVICIO QUE RECIBA EL TOKEN Y LO ALAMCENE EN EL LOCAL STORAGE, Y EN BASE A ESE TOKEN SI EL ROL QUE DEVULEVE ES ADMINISTRADOR ENTONCES QUE EL GUARD DEVUELVA TRUE DE LO CONTRARIO QUE DEVUELVA FALSE */
```

```
 user.guard.ts 
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class UserGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private readonly router: Router) { }

    canActivate(): boolean {


        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

        if (token) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

```
auth.routing.module.ts


import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';


const routes: Routes = [

  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}

]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: el selector de la directiva es `formGroup` con la efe inicial en minúscula

Comment: que raro antes lo ponia en minuscula y tambien me salia error pero ya no me sale error resaltado, pregunta se supone que en los archivos que envie , cuando yo coloco en el puerto `http://localhost:4200/dashboard` no deberia redirigirme a esa vista si no me logueo,deberia redirigirme al login porque no he puesto credenciales, que tengo mal o que deberia cambiar, antes si me estaba funcionando y lo tenia igual el codigo practicamente

Comment: Pues eso te puede suceder, o porque no hayas configurado bien la guarda en la ruta del dashboard, o porque sigas teniendo un `token` en `localStorage`  cuando estés intentando acceder a la ruta.

Comment: deberia poner la ruta del dashboard en el archivo de guard?es que la verdad no te entiendo ,  asi tengo mis archivos como estan arriba

Comment: En el código de la pregunta no veo donde tienes definida la ruta del dashboard (supongo que a tendrás en el `AppRoutingModule`), y ahi es donde tienes que tener configurada la guarda, para que angular la compruebe al acceder a ella. De todas formas, nos estamos desviando del tema de la pregunta original y probablemente seria mejor que crearas una nueva para el nuevo problema. saludos